# Cómo escribir el comando para SFC en modo manual para reparar archivos desde Powershell

Tags: powershell

estoy aprendiendo con Powershell y estaba interesado en saber como se desglosa el  comando SFC.

Con estos ej:

1- sfc /VERIFYFILE=c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll
2- sfc /SCANFILE=d:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll /OFFBOOTDIR=d:\ /OFFWINDIR=d:\windows
3- sfc /SCANFILE=d:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll /OFFBOOTDIR=d:\ /OFFWINDIR=d:\windows /OFFLOGFILE=c:\log.txt

No comprendo que se tiene que poner y que significa los /OFFBOOTDIR=d:\ /OFFWINDIR=d:\windows

Gracias